# python timer in minutes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run the below code. It fails to run for 5 minutes, can you please let me know what the issue is here. I am trying to run this in background by saving as `.pyw` and alert me after finishing 1 hours, as per what is passed in timer arguments.

```
import time
import ctypes
def timer(minutes):
    seconds = minutes * 60
    start = time.time()
    time.clock()
    elapsed = 0
    while elapsed < seconds:
        elapsed = time.time() - start
    time.sleep(1)
    timer(5) #would want enter in hours not in seconds
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0,"DoneToday", "Dones", 0)
```

Comment: You can do by this `from threading import Timer`

Comment: Waiting N seconds by doing a busy loop is a terrible idea. Your CPU will work at 100% and interfere with everything else running on the system. You are already aware of `time.sleep` - use that instead of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `timer()` function is infinitely looping.

After your `while elapsed < seconds:` loop, two lines down, you've put `timer(5)`. So that just calls itself again, and again, again...

Once you remove this line, it will work as expected:

```
timer(5) #would want enter in hours not in seconds
```

And as @vermillon mentioned, any reason you're not just doing `time.sleep(minutes * 60)`? I'm assuming you plan to do something else in that loop, other than just counting time.

---

Edit: For the OP to see running code

```
>>> def timer(minutes):
...     seconds = minutes * 60
...     start = time.time()
...     time.clock()
...     elapsed = 0
...     while elapsed < seconds:
...         elapsed = time.time() - start
...     time.sleep(1)
...     ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0,"DoneToday", "Dones", 0)
...     print 'also printing Done so you can see it'
...
>>> timer(0.1)
also printing Done so you can see it
>>>
```

Comment: timer(5) #would want enter in hours not in seconds.. would not want to remove this line because i am passing this argument 5 mins

Comment: Infinite recursion occurs and the function never ends. You're already converting from minutes to seconds on the line `seconds = minutes * 60`. So why is `timer()` calling itself? That line has nothing to do with what you're trying to do. And if you want to use hours, do `seconds = hours * 60 * 60` instead of `minutes`. Remove the line as directed and you'll see that it works exactly as expected.

Comment: ran like as you said i commented ...but nothing happens with below code..import time
import ctypes
def timer(minutes):
 seconds = minutes * 60
 start = time.time()
 time.clock()
 elapsed = 0
 while elapsed < seconds:
  elapsed = time.time() - start
 time.sleep(seconds)
 #timer(1) #would want enter in hours not inseconds
 ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0,"Done", "Done", 0)

Comment: I ran your code with just the one change as I've mentioed above. It ran fine for me. I ran it with `timer(0.1)` (6 seconds). You are 'running' your function, right? And not just stopping after the `def`? I'll add my code to the answer so you can actually see it.

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/193893)

Comment: Running below sometimes fails to alert after 9 hours and more over it's consuming 30% or more CPU, when I check in Task Manager.


import time
import ctypes
def timer(hours):
 seconds = hours * 3600
 start = time.time()
 time.clock()
 elapsed = 0
 while elapsed < seconds:
 elapsed = time.time() - start
 elapsed = elapsed//60
 ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0,"GetOut "+str(elapsed),  "Done", 0)
timer(9)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a timer that shows minutes and seconds remaining, then here's the snippet for you:

```
import time
import sys

def run_timer(seconds):
    for remaining in range(seconds, 0, -1):
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        minutes = 0
        seconds = remaining
        if remaining > 60:
            minutes = int(seconds/60)
            seconds = int(seconds%60)
        else:
            seconds = remaining
        sys.stdout.write("{:2d} minutes {:2d} seconds remaining.".format(minutes,seconds)) 
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write("Timer complete") 

run_timer(120)
```